# Two select_date in form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form_tag with two "select_date"

```
<%= form_tag installation_path, :method => :get, :class => 'form-search' do %>
<%= select_date(date = Date.current, options = {}, html_options = {}) %>
<%= select_date(date2 = Date.current, options = {}, html_options = {}) %>
```

In backend I dont receive date2, I only receive date but in the view 2 select_date are displayed. When I inspect params I only see 1 and I dont know why

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "date"=>{"day"=>"21", "month"=>"11", "year"=>"2015"}...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prefixes:

```
<%= form_tag installation_path, :method => :get, :class => 'form-search' do %>
<%= select_date(Date.current, prefix: "date1") %>
<%= select_date(Date.current, prefix: "date2") %>
```

You will get:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "date1"=>{"day"=>"21", "month"=>"11", "year"=>"2015"}, "date2"=>{"day"=>"21", "month"=>"11", "year"=>"2015"}...}
```